# KDB share table in memory

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to have two KDB processes referencing one, read-only table loaded into the main memory? They should be able to read it independently of each other. Requirement is to load the data from disk once. I came up with an awkward solution of starting one Q(producer) to load the table and the rest of Q processes (consumers) connecting locally and pulling the table over the socket. In the nutshell, I am trying to multi-process my select queries. Thanks

Comment: Can you start the process with a negative port? Is this what you're looking for http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/MultithreadedInputMode

Comment: Chromozorz - thank you. I am going to check this out. I thought of individual KDB processes started on the same server(node) using shared memory data ie. table t.

Comment: Great, let me know if it is what you're looking for. Otherwise I will post an answer. Cheers

Comment: In addition to @Chromozorz ' s comment, see http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Cmdlineb to block write access (i.e. make the table read only)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

KDB mmaps on [get](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#get), so simply have one core build your table and [save](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#save) it (optionally [splayed](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#dsave)), and then tell the other tables to get it:

```
`:table set build_table ([] ...);
other_cores @\: ({table:get x};`:table);
```